# How to make Interface in iOS

Tags: ios

I have a page which I have to create in iOS. Below I have uploaded the screen shots of one page. How can I create this page. please suggest to some links or some ideas to create this interface.

Answer (score 0):

This tutorial is what helped me.  It's quite a lot to type out in an answer here.  The big trick is adding a content view inside the scroll view and adding all your content to that content view

http://spin.atomicobject.com/2014/03/05/uiscrollview-autolayout-ios/

Answer (score 0):

I am not vary experienced with using the `UIScrollView` but I think this is how you do it:

[image]

Search for the scroll view the Object Library and place it on you storyboard, then re-size it to your needs. (I am assuming you are using interface builder)

I am probably missing something here though.

Answer (score 0):

If you already have a view that you would like to embed in a `UIScrollView`, go to "Editor" and select "Embed in scroll view":

[image]

Comment: does this take care of all the autolayout constraints too?  That would be awesome if it did

Comment: @Steve Not entirely, you'll probably have to do a little bit of auto layout editing still.

Answer (score 0):

I would use a `UITableView` here.  `UITableView` is a subclass of `UIScrollView`.  You can use the `UITableViewCell`'s to break up the different components in your view.

Comment: How to use UITableViewCell's to break up the different components in my view.please suggest

Comment: This should be a good starting point http://www.appcoda.com/uitableview-tutorial-storyboard-xcode5/